# Is there any symbolic set theory software?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, math-software

Is there a good software for doing symbolic set theory problems?

For example defining irrational numbers as infinite sets. And manipulating expressions. And all those sorts of things?

It doesn't look like Mathematica, Maple of Maxima do this except in the simple cast of finite sets. Such as doing simple Unions etc.

And then there are some computer proof systems that are based on very low level set theory concepts.

Is there any middle ground?

Comment: I don’t understand. What would such a software do exactly ?

Comment: @Pjonin define sets, do calculations with them, unions, same as normal algebraic software but with sets.

Comment: Take your brand new neural network computer to class with you and train it to do set theory homework.